# Cordova / Android: Use java method in Javascript to list file in resources

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to list all the files in a specific folder in my a Javascript that I use to manipulate my HTMLs. 
I'm using a java method to list all the files that I to display.

Here's the the class.

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

private Context context;

public JavaScriptInterface(Context current){
    this.context = current;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public List<String> getFileNames(String path){
    String [] files;

    try {
        files = context.getAssets().list(path);
        ArrayList<String> testName = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String  file: files) {
            Log.d("File name: ", file);
            file = file.replace(".js", "");
            String[] fileName = file.split("_");
            testName.add(fileName[1]);
        }
        return testName;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Then I added this in my mainActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    setToUnstrictMode();
    WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
    wV.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "jsInterface");

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    wV.loadUrl(launchUrl);
}
```

Then I tried accessing it in my JS using this function.

```
var getTestNames = function(){
    return window.jsInterface.getFileNames("www/js/tests");
}
```

Apparently, It's not working.

EDIT: I noticed that I was able to call the method, the log from the method getFileNames shows up in my logs. However, for some reasons, I could not pass it properly in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just write a simple plugin. I wrote some by myself i can approve that they are working. Use tips from official cordova documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html
I know that it's different approach, but at least it's a working one.